# Element is not clickable at point (80, 82). Other element would receive the click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Angular application which I want to automate using Java and Selenium Web Driver. In my case I have tab which is displayed after progress bar:

```
    // Wait Progress bar to finish
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));

    // Listener to click on the tab:

    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
    System.out.println("Click on Tab " + name + " using id locator " + tabId);
    WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(tabId)));
    webElement.click();
```

In graphical mode it's working fine. But when I try to run it into background into Headless Chrome mode I get exception:

```
element click intercepted: Element <div cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="mat-tab-label mat-ripple mat-tab-label-active ng-star-inserted" mat-ripple="" mattablabelwrapper="" role="tab" id="mat-tab-label-0-0" tabindex="0" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="3" aria-controls="mat-tab-content-0-0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">...</div> is not clickable at point (80, 82). Other element would receive the click: <video width="240" height="320" controls="">...</video>
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DTXA-ENVTEST01', ip: 'xxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 90.0.4430.212, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da..., userDataDir: C:\Users\devadmin\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51589}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 27f7f44c1429bbda4e137629c2f9ae52
```

Stack trace

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: 
element click intercepted: Element <div cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="mat-tab-label mat-ripple mat-tab-label-active ng-star-inserted" mat-ripple="" mattablabelwrapper="" role="tab" id="mat-tab-label-0-0" tabindex="0" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="3" aria-controls="mat-tab-content-0-0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">...</div> is not clickable at point (80, 82). Other element would receive the click: <video width="240" height="320" controls="">...</video>
(Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DTXA-ENVTEST01', ip: 'xxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 90.0.4430.212, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da..., userDataDir: C:\Users\devadmin\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51589}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 27f7f44c1429bbda4e137629c2f9ae52
at org.mobile.LoginScreenTest.verifyMainMenuLandingScreenTest(LoginScreenTest.java:411)
```

What could be the problem? Is there some more suitable `ExpectedConditions` than `elementToBeClickable` in this case?

Looks like into headless mode the progress animation is not paused and there is a click produced immutably. Can you advice?

Comment: Is the locator you are using to click is right?

Comment: @PeterPenzov : Updated that as an answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code :

`new Actions(driver).moveToElement(webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(tabId)))).click().build().perform();`

> with both (with UI and Headless)

Comment: I use the latest stable maven version: `<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>` Is it possible that in latest beta version this might be fixed?

Comment: Well, `Element is not clickable at point (X, Y). Other element would receive the click
` is a generic error where Selenium has a difficulty to focus within it's current view port. Actions class let the driver has the focus on the elements we wanna to interact. This is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess without seeing the screenshot of the failure, but I'll try.
There are several things I think about that can help.

1. Start browser maximized with

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

2. Use element visibility instead of clickability

```
WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible(By.id(tabId)));
webElement.click();
```

3. Use JavaScript click instead of WebDriver click

```
WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(tabId)));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```